# Appending a tuple as value to dictionary by using map() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I am writing a function that returns a dictionary with the year of the docs as key and, as value, it specifies a tuple that is returned by def do_get_citations_per_year function.

So far, I managed to create a dictionary with keys as years. I am stuck at how should I map those two functions so that to obtain a tuple as a value.

```
#the function that returns tuple which I need as a value.
def do_get_citations_per_year(data, year):
    result = tuple()
    my_ocan['creation'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(my_ocan['creation']).year

    len_citations = len(my_ocan.loc[my_ocan["creation"] == year, "creation"])
    timespan = round(my_ocan.loc[my_ocan["creation"] == year, "timespan"].mean())
    result = (len_citations, timespan)
    print(result)


    return result


def do_get_citations_all_years(data):
    mydict = {}
    t = tuple()
    series_name = my_ocan.creation
    s = set(series_name)
    for year in s:
        mydict[year] = ()

    for key in mydict.keys():
        mydict[key].append()##???How can I use map() function here: 



    return mydict
```

Answer (score 0):

[Tuples](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) are immutable - you can't append to them. Why don't you just do the following:

```
def do_get_citations_all_years(data):
    mydict = {}
    series_name = my_ocan.creation
    s = set(series_name)
    for year in s:
        mydict[year] = do_get_citations_per_year(data, year)
    return mydict
```

Or even:

```
def do_get_citations_all_years(data):
    return {year: do_get_citations_per_year(data, year) for year in set(my_ocan.creation)}
```

It should be noted that the `data` arguments to both of your functions are redundant, as you don't use `data` within either of them, you use `my_ocan`.

Comment: Hey! Thank you very much for answering my question:) I tried your solution and now I have the error                                                                      timespan = round(my_ocan.loc[my_ocan["creation"] == year, "timespan"].mean())
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer. I cannot get why the error occurs since timespan column does not have Nan values, only 0.0, moreover, when I separately run the first function, checking the set of dictionary keys, it gives output without an error